# Merge Syntax with NULL Values

Tags: sql, sql-merge

Say I want to compare my Source and Target Table using MERGE syntax in SQL

I want to update the End_Dt of my target table when `target.close_Date` is not equal to `Source.Close_Date`.

Table 1

```
ID   Close_Date   End_Date
1    NULL         9999-12-31
```

Table 2

```
ID   Close_Date
1    2019-01-31
```

```
Merge Table1 as Target
Using Table 2 as Source
On (Target.ID = Source.ID_)
WHEN MATCHED and 
isnull(Target.Closed_Date,'9999-12-31') = isnull(Source.Closed_Date,'9999-12-31')
THEN
Update Set Table1.End_Dt = cast(getdate() as date));
```

After I ran the code nothing is updated in my target table.

Comment: please add a tag of your dbms

Comment: Why are you using `merge` instead of `update`?